# Filling NoData around bridges in DEM

Tags: dem, nodata

Is it possible to fill no data around bridges without pixels blurriness (see picture). I use Elevation Void fill function, also tried in qgis No data filling and Grassgis r.fillnulls. I know, that I can just assing all Nodata values to specific value, but I need to get smooth raster.

before

[image]

after
[image]

Comment: Could you please upload this raster in order to try something with your own data ?

Comment: sorry, I can't upload it, but thank you for response. Maybe you can explain how can I try to solve this problem?

Comment: So what values do you actually want to put into the no data? What are you starting at and what do you end at. How are you making that choice? As it looks like a river it would be nonsense to increase as you go upstream. How do plan to exclude what I assume are buildings on the land? Which direction do you want to fill values. I think you need to provide significantly more information, what other datasets do you have to accomplish this task?

Comment: Actually in this case it doesn't metter what values are in the rivers or buildings, I just need to make DTM with bridges that visualy will be clear

Comment: You need to use breaklines to accomplish what you want